# Android 4 Emulator Camera Server Died

Tags: android, android-camera

```
11-11 20:13:39.831: W/Camera(767): ICamera died
11-11 20:13:39.831: W/Camera(767): Camera server died!
11-11 20:13:39.842: E/Camera(767): Error 100
```

Hello I have been working on this problem for a while.  I have all the permission set correctly in Manifest file, and am doing the correct Camera.open and setting up a CameraPreview (Surface View) like in the Android.com example.  However, I continually get the Camera server error when the `startPreview()` method is invoked in the following method of CameraPreview class.

Any ideas?  I have scoured the web for solutions, this method is not called until after the onResume and the Camera is opened successfully.

```
//method of CameraPreview (extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback)
//that is associated with a view added to a FrameLayout in my App

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw the preview.
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            mCamera.startPreview();//HERE IS WHERE IT IS CAUSING ERROR!!!!!
        } catch (IOException e) {
          //  Log.d(TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Run your code in debug mode and post previous log errors (if exist) pls

Comment: Have you found a solution? Please share